# Do Convergence in Distribution and Convergence of the Variances determine the Variance of the Limit?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose we have a sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that satisfies:

- $X_n \rightarrow_d X$, for $n\rightarrow \infty$, where $\rightarrow_d$ denotes convergence in distribution;
- $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)$ exists for all $n$ (i.e., it is finite), and $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)\rightarrow c\in\mathrm{R}$, for  $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Does that imply that $c=\mathrm{Var}(X)$? If yes, how could one prove it. If no, is there a counterexample?

Many thanks for any help, I much appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, try the distributions given by $\mathbb P(X_n=\sqrt{n})=\mathbb P(X_n=-\sqrt{n})=\frac1{2n}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=0)=1-\frac1n$. But one always has $\mathrm{var}(X)\leqslant\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{var}(X_n)$.

(To ensure the convergence $\mathrm{var}(X)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{var}(X_n)$, one usually adds to the convergence in distribution $X_n\to X$, some uniform integrability condition.)

Comment: Is variance converging to related to $L^2$ convergence in anyway?

Comment: Are you claiming the statment the OP posted is true if $X_n$'s are uniformly integrable?

Comment: @Lost1 First comment: in English please. Second comment: ??

Comment: thanks @Did, nice example. do you know, by any chance, what uniform integrability conditions (uniform integrability of the $X_n$'s is enough?) that would ensure the desired limiting variance property?

Comment: A sufficient condition is that the sequence $(X_n^2)$ is uniformly integrable. And to ensure *that*, one can ask that $\mathbb E(|X_n|^\alpha)\leqslant C$ for every $n$, for some finite $C$ and $\alpha\gt2$ (the example shows that $\alpha=2$ is not enough).

Comment: excellent, many thanks for your answer!